# compare file size between two identical non sparse files while copying

Tags: files, ls, size

I'm using KVM to live migrate VMs from one host to another.
I have already written a web ui to do that. Now I want to implement a progress bar.

My idea is to compare the file size of the disk on the source and on the target while it's migrating.

**Server1:**

```
ls -ls /data/file.raw
858963 -rw------- 1 root root 21474836480 Dec 15 13:39 file.raw
```

**Server2:**

```
ls -ls /data/file.raw
698543 -rw------- 1 root root 21474836480 Dec 15 13:39 file.raw
```

Now, I took the allocated value and calculated it in percent.

100 / 858963 * 698543 = 81%

Fine. but there is one problem:

The disk is not sparse. The total size of the file is `1717926 blocks`.
Actually, there are only `858963 blocks` allocated. So the live migration is still copying the empty parts of the file while my progress bar is already at 100%

I already tried around with `du` and `stat`.

How to get only the transferred file size of the disk?

Comment: The file, not the disk, is sparse. Try `du -h /data/file.raw` (real disk use) and `du  -h --apparent-size /data/file.raw`. What do you use (with all args) to transfer the file?

Comment: I'm using libvirt to migrate the VM. `virsh migrate --verbose --live --copy-storage-all $VM_NAME qemu+ssh://$TARGET/system` According to the docs, it is using rsync. `du -h` returns `858M` and `du -h --apparent-size` returns `6.0G`

Comment: See https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1219541

Answer (score 0):

Use virsh migrate as already suggested, or take advantage of rsync's sparse files support, from `man rsync`:

`-S, --sparse
              Try to handle sparse files efficiently so they take up
              less  space on the destination.`

Try `rsync -ahHS`, add `-P` if you want to see progress and speed